# How to send an email with attachment from R in windows

Tags: r, email, sendmailr

I have a scheduled an R script running from a windows machine.

After it finishes, I wish this script to automatically send an email with some log file attached.

Using `shell()` with some other scripts may be possible, but I was wondering if there is a better solution within R. 
Thanks.

Comment: I presume you meant `system()` when you wrote `shell()`.

Comment: Hi Ahala, I hope Stedy solution will help.  Might I ask, what do you use to have a scheduled R script?  Thanks.

Comment: Tal, use Scheduled tasks in Windows (I reckon that entry goes something like R CMD BATCH script.R), cron on *NIX sistems.

Answer (score 51):

sendmailR works for me on Windows 7. I referenced http://cran.es.r-project.org/web/packages/sendmailR/sendmailR.pdf

smtpServer= info for Outlook 2010 is in File -> Account Settings -> Account Settings -> double click your account -> text in "Server" box

```
library(sendmailR)

#set working directory
setwd("C:/workingdirectorypath")

#####send plain email

from <- "you@account.com"
to <- "recipient@account.com"
subject <- "Email Subject"
body <- "Email body."                     
mailControl=list(smtpServer="serverinfo")

sendmail(from=from,to=to,subject=subject,msg=body,control=mailControl)

#####send same email with attachment

#needs full path if not in working directory
attachmentPath <- "subfolder/log.txt"

#same as attachmentPath if using working directory
attachmentName <- "log.txt"

#key part for attachments, put the body and the mime_part in a list for msg
attachmentObject <- mime_part(x=attachmentPath,name=attachmentName)
bodyWithAttachment <- list(body,attachmentObject)

sendmail(from=from,to=to,subject=subject,msg=bodyWithAttachment,control=mailControl)
```

In addition, multiple files can be sent by adding another mime_part to the msg list as follows (I also condensed it):

```
attachmentObject <- mime_part(x="subfolder/log.txt",name="log.txt")
attachmentObject2 <- mime_part(x="subfolder/log2.txt",name="log2.txt")
bodyWithAttachment <- list(body,attachmentObject,attachmentObject2)
```

Comment: Can you use html in "Email body."? Can you use utf-8 encoding (for multilingual text)?

Comment: I don't know. Try it and see.

Comment: How do you configure the serverinfo part for gmail?

Comment: I don't think sendmailR accepts authentication (user/password) - I use mailR for this reason.

Comment: @Andreas Your statement appears true http://www.statistik.tu-dortmund.de/~olafm/software/sendmailR/

Answer (score 21):

Use [mailR](https://github.com/rpremraj/mailR) - it works with authentication, attachments, it automatically send txt message along with html and more.

`mailR` requires rJava which can be a bit of a pain sometimes. On windows I haven't had any problems. On ubuntu this solved the one issue I've had:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-jdk
```

in R

```
install.packages("devtools", dep = T)
library(devtools)
install_github("rpremraj/mailR")
```

(if you have trouble with rJava - try `sudo R CMD javareconf` in terminal)

`mailR` is easy to work with and well documented on the github page.

Example from the documentaion

```
library(mailR)
send.mail(from = "sender@gmail.com",
          to = c("recipient1@gmail.com", "recipient2@gmail.com"),
          subject = "Subject of the email",
          body = "Body of the email",
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = "gmail_username", passwd = "password", ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE,
          attach.files = c("./download.log", "upload.log", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5031586/How%20to%20use%20the%20Public%20folder.rtf"),
          file.names = c("Download log.log", "Upload log.log", "DropBox File.rtf"), # optional parameter
          file.descriptions = c("Description for download log", "Description for upload log", "DropBox File"), # optional parameter
          debug = TRUE)
```

Note: your smtp server might find excessive use suspicious. This is the case with e.g. gmail. So after sending a few mails you probably have to log in to the [gmail account](https://security.google.com/settings/u/1/security/notifications) and see if the account has been temporarily disabled. Also note that if you use a gmail account with two-factor authentication you need to use [an application specific password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833).

Comment: Perhaps you could include an example from the documentation to demonstrate what the code would look like. The other answers successfully included examples.

Comment: @Andreas For attachments, I tried using fileInput function that allows the users to select the file instead of hardcoding the file name...but it returns an error `Error in file.exists: invalid 'file' argument`...any thoughts?

Answer (score 10):

Would you settle for a twitter message?  You could use Rcurl to post an update to twitter, which can then be forwarded to your cell phone as a text, or to your email via the notification settings.

See here: http://www.sakana.fr/blog/2007/03/18/scripting-twitter-with-curl/

Comment: There is a CRAN package called twitteR for interfacing twitter from R: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/index.html

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked into the `sendmailR` package yet?  It allows SMTP to submit a message and you could probably edit the function to allow an attachment.  Then again, if its only one log file it might just be worth it to use `shell()` as you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows one might parse together a VB-Script (see e.g. http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm ) and then call it via shell.

This might look like this:

```
SendMail <- function(from="me@my-server.de",to="me@my-server.de",text="Hallo",subject="Sag Hallo",smtp="smtp.my.server.de",user="me.myself.and.i",pw="123"){
require(stringr)
part1 <- "Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1 'Send message using the local SMTP service pickup directory. 
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network). 
Const cdoAnonymous = 0 'Do not authenticate
Const cdoBasic = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication 
Const cdoNTLM = 2 'NTLM "

part2 <- paste(paste("Set objMessage = CreateObject(",'"',"CDO.Message",'"',")" ,sep=""),
paste("objMessage.Subject = ",'"',subject,'"',sep=""),
paste("objMessage.From = ",'"',from,'"',sep=""),
paste("objMessage.To = ",'"',to,'"',sep=""),
paste("objMessage.TextBody = ",'"',text,'"',sep=""),
sep="\n")

part3 <- paste(
"'==This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server. 

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
(\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing\") = 2

'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server 
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
(\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver\") = ",'"',smtp,'"'," 

'Type of authentication, NONE, Basic (Base64 encoded), NTLM 
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
(\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate\") = cdoBasic 

'Your UserID on the SMTP server 
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
(\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername\") = ",'"',user,'"'," 

'Your password on the SMTP server 
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
(\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword\") = ",'"',pw,'"', "

'Server port (typically 25) 
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
(\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport\") = 25 

'Use SSL for the connection (False or True) 
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
(\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl\") = False 

'Connection Timeout in seconds (the maximum time CDO will try to establish a connection to the SMTP server) 
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
(\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout\") = 60 
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

'==End remote SMTP server configuration section== 

objMessage.Send 
",sep="")

vbsscript <- paste(part1,part2,part3,sep="\n\n\n")
str_split(vbsscript,"\n")
writeLines(vbsscript, "sendmail.vbs")
shell("sendmail.vbs")
unlink("sendmail.vbs")
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works like a dream! This is the only approach I have found to work in R (on Windows). As explained in Paul's web page, if you use gmail you need to set the server port to 465 and to set the "Use SSL" option to True. I used the following code to call it: `SendMail(from="dag.hjermann@gmail.com",to="dhj@niva.no",text="Hallo", subject="Sag Hallo",smtp="smtp.gmail.com",user="dag.hjermann@gmail.com",pw="********")` Insert your real password of course... Also, the work directory of R must be somewhere on the hard disk (C:).

Comment: This is awesome!  Is it possible to add an attachment?  I have very limited VB experience...so, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Love to help :-) ... jip, it seems possible although I never tried it myself, see here: http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm under headline "Sending a text email with an attached file" ... one could include the relevant lines in the function.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to remind people who wants self-notifying feature of a service called twilio, they provide free service to send sms to your own cellphone. A walk-through using R is available here https://dreamtolearn.com/ryan/data_analytics_viz/78

An example code is attached, just replace the credentials with the ones of your own.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(XML)
library(httr)
library(rjson)
library(RCurl)
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))

authenticate_twilio <- "https://[ACCOUNT SID]:[AUTH TOKEN]@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts"
authenticate_response <- getURL(authenticate_twilio)
print(authenticate_response)

postForm("https://[ACCOUNT SID]:[AUTH TOKEN]@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[ACCOUNT SID]/Messages.XML",.params = c(From = "+1[twilio phone#]", To = "+1[self phone#]",Body = "Hello from twilio"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code snippet for sending an e-mail by using "mailR" package

```
library(mailR)

# 1. Sender
sender <- "x@me.com"

# 2. Recipients
recipients <- c("y@you.com", "z@our.com")

# 3. Attached files
list_files_attached_location <- c("mtcars.csv")
list_files_attached_names <- c("mtcars name")
list_files_attached_description <- c("mtcars desc")

# 4. Send email
tryCatch({
  send.mail(from = sender,
            to = recipients,
            subject = "Your subject",
            body = "Your mail body",
            smtp = list(
              host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", 
              port = 465,
              user.name = sender,
              passwd = "psw", 
              ssl = TRUE),
            authenticate = TRUE,
            send = TRUE,
            attach.files = list_files_attached_location,
            file.names = list_files_attached_names,
            file.descriptions = list_files_attached_description,
            debug = TRUE
  )
}, 
error = function(e) {
  print(e)
  stop()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who suggested using 'mailR' - this is the way to go, but it is difficult to install of ubuntu. Here is a resource to install 'javaR' on ubuntu which will allow you to install 'mailR'

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/02/installing-rjava-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Late to this, but you can  avoid shelling out to vbscript by using RDCOMClient correctly, as in [this example](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-July/037021.html) from R-Help.

```
> sendEmail(ema = "r-help at r-project.org", 
        name = "R-help mailing list",
        subject = "How to send Email from R using the RDCOMClient"
        msgBody = "here is the body of the message")

The package RDCOMClient is available at http://www.omegahat.org/RDCOMClient.

"sendEmail" <-
function(ema, name, subject, msgBody, deliverNow = TRUE)
{
   require(RDCOMClient)

   ema <- paste("SMPT:", ema, sep="")   ## prepend protocol to address

   ## create an e-mail session 
   session <- COMCreate("Mapi.Session") 
   session$Logon()

   ## add a message to the outbox collection of messages
   outbox <- session[["Outbox"]]
   msg <- outbox[["Messages"]]$Add(subject, msgBody)

   ## add recipient's name  (TODO: addMultiple() or loop, if many recipients)
   msg[["Recipients"]]$Add(name, ema) 
   msg$Send()
   if(deliverNow)
      msg$DeliverNow()

   session$Logoff()   ## wrap up
}
```