# Is it possible to get notifications when user uploads file on ShinyApp?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

Pretty self explanatory, I am wondering if it is possible to get automated notifications pushed via email if an app user uploads a file.

Some initial thoughts are using an action button (i.e. ‘Submit’) and observe the event to tigger the notification. However - this does not seem possible without using sendmailR.

I have tried using HTML-and while this works fine for users to send mail - it is not automated and the user will have to interact with client mail service (e.g Outlook).

Now, my app already stores the submitted data on the dirpath on server,but I would like to get notified to mitigate having to continuously check the relevant folders to see if there are new data entries.

Any ideas?

Comment: This should be possible with `sendmailR`. Here is a usage example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20863363/1100107

Comment: Yeah I will try to work this out. It isn’t cooperating with the server.