# Get R's computation results from a distant computer

Tags: r, ssh-tunnel

Let's say that `R` is running a computation on Computer A.

Can computer B "take a look" at how this `R` computation is going on computer A?

Can `R` send the output (maybe even the created files) to a computer B when the computation is done?

I know `R` has a `sink()` function but I don't know how to use it with a distant computer, or even if that woukd be an appropriate way to set things up for my purpose. Should I use a SSH tunnel (whatever that means)?

@Enrico & @Señor O:

Computers A and B are PCs. I don't have admin rights on computer A, so I probably can't install a SSH server or "mount" computer B (does it mean creating a network?) on it.

Maybe I can send myself an email from R though? Saying something like "computation reached this point, here is the output so far..."

I just found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885660/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-from-r-in-windows)  that this might be easily set up. Apparently you can even twitter from R!

Comment: Depends on the machine you're using. On my mac, I can write an R object to another computer mounted on mine via `save(R_Object_Name, file="/Volumes/ComputerName/...")`

Comment: I wrote a [blog post](http://johnbaumgartner.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/rbot/) some time ago describing the use of Twitter (via Twidge, although the `twitteR` package should suffice) to send me direct messages that notify me of computation progress and summarise results. You can also have R save files (e.g., plots, `sink` output, etc.) in a Dropbox folder that you can access remotely. There are also some apps that you can install on A, which have web interfaces that you could use to "take a look" from B. I'm not 100%, but think [Logmein](https://secure.logmein.com/UK/) doesn't need install on B.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you should be able to do this quite easily with a combination of ssh and tmux (or screen).

Computer A must have a ssh server running.

```
user@computerB$ ssh computerA.domain.com
user@computerA$ tmux new
user@computerA$ R
> source("myAnalysis.R")
...
```

Press `Ctrl-b d` to detach and then `Ctrl-d` to disconnect from computer A. Now you can shut down your computer, go for a walk, whatever. Then:

```
user@computerB$ ssh computerA.domain.com
user@computerA$ tmux a
>
```

R will still be running.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open the `.Rout` file if you run R in batch mode without interrupting the job. Copy it and open the copy to be extra-safe. As to copying the output, it might be easiest to write a bash script to run R in batch mode and then scp the output files once the job is done.