# how do you send email from R

Tags: r

I want to send emails from R. This is what I have so far:

```
library(sendmailR)


from <- "eamil@example.com"
to <- "email2@example.com"
subject <- "Performance Result"
body <- "This is the result of the test:"                     
mailControl=list(smtpServer="snmpt server address")

sendmail(from=from,to=to,subject=subject,msg=body,control=mailControl)
```

When I execute this script, my R session hangs. Any ideas what might be happening?

Comment: It would be awesome know how to solve this problem I always got error trying to use this function @user1471980

Comment: what's your operating system?

Comment: Does [mailR](https://github.com/rpremraj/mailR) work using the same config?

Comment: You need to set a valid `smtpServer` and valid email address in `to`. Not to mention that this is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885660/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-from-r-in-windows

Comment: @Duck sure it works on Windows or any other operating system, you just need an SMTP somewhere, probably not on your machine running R. E.g. you can use your ISP's mail server.

Comment: Thanks dear @daroczig I think the problem is with outlook because it doesn't give me SMTP direction. Maybe any advice of how to get it.

Comment: I tried the mailR, sendmailR, and [blastula](https://rich-iannone.github.io/blastula/reference/smtp_send.html) suggestions with no success. And [SMS from R via Twilio](http://seankross.com/2017/03/07/Send-a-Text-from-R-with-Twilio.html) didn't appeal to me.
Finally settled on a less elegant but simple solution: write a text file to OneDrive, which I never use, and allow notifications on my phone because all I wanted was a notification when a long-running model finished. Could have been any cloud drive, but I don't allow notifications from Dropbox because they would be too frequent.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just tried it out, and it worked for me.

My only differences were I used <> for the from and to:

```
from = "<email1@dal.ca>"
to = "<email2@gmail.com>"
```

and my mail control was different, I used

```
control=list(smtpServer="ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM"))
```

Comment: I am using Windows (8.1), but I don't use outlook, so I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Thanks @Sarah maybe do you know how to get `smtpServer` on Windows

Comment: @Duck What would it mean for R to be able to send mail on Outlook?

Comment: @isomorphismes Considering microsoft office outlook

Comment: @Duck The mail can be sent through R `xor` Outlook; those options are mutually exclusive.

Comment: This does not work for me anymore ( it did an year ago). I used `sendmail` with the above-mentioned SMTP server, but it gave me an error ```In socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) :
  ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM:25 cannot be opened```

Comment: Using the `<` and `>` around the "from" address allowed me to send "from" a shared office email mailbox (while still authenticating using my own email address and password). Thanks for this tip!

Answer (score 51):

If you need to be able to use an smtp server with authentication you can use the `mailR` package.

For example using gmail's smtp server:

```
library(mailR)
sender <- "SENDER@gmail.com"
recipients <- c("RECIPIENT@gmail.com")
send.mail(from = sender,
          to = recipients,
          subject = "Subject of the email",
          body = "Body of the email",
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, 
                      user.name = "YOURUSERNAME@gmail.com",            
                      passwd = "YOURPASSWORD", ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

Comment: I recieve such an error: `Error in ls(envir = envir, all.names = private) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument`

Comment: I cannot replicate your error. The code works for me like it is. Consider asking a new question where you describe how to reproduce this error and probably someone will be able to help you. Maybe [this](https://github.com/rpremraj/mailR/issues/15) helps.

Comment: @MarcinKosinski I got that error as well but then restarted R and it worked for me.

Comment: Worked so far so good for me, using a corporate Google Apps account. Tks.+1

Comment: does this still work? I get a critical security warning mail from google when attempting it and then on R side `Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465`. Am i assuming correctly that `SENDER@gmail.com` and `YOURUSERNAME@gmail.com` would be the same?

Comment: @BigDataScientist the code still works if you [allow less secure apps access](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) in your gmail settings. The question is if you want to accept any risks associated with it.

Comment: thanks that helped when i tried it locally. On EC2 it still fails unfortunately, will keep looking.

Comment: @BigDataScientist there are many SMTP providers (most of them with free tiers for few hundred emails per month). If you are using EC2, Amazon offers free SMTP server for the first 62000 emails called [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/)

Comment: Does this code still work?  I had something similar and it recently stopped working for me.

Comment: @P__2 You have to [allow less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) in your google account to work. If you use 2FA then you cannot use that option. You could search for an alternative free SMTP server

Comment: less secure apps was disabled on May 30th 2022.  I created an [app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833#zippy=%2Cyou-still-cant-sign-in) and that worked for me.

Answer (score 19):

Sorry for bumping up this thread. If you want to send email from R using Microsoft outlook, below is the way to go using the `RDCOMClient` package. I myself spent a lot of time trying to find an answer on this. I thought it would be useful to have this solution too in this thread for users.

Full credit to @agstudy who provided the original solution in this link - [Sending email in R via outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811679/sending-email-in-r-via-outlook)

```
library (RDCOMClient)

OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
outMail[["To"]] = "test@test.com"
outMail[["subject"]] = "Test Subject"
outMail[["body"]] = "Body of email"               
outMail$Send()
```

Comment: Is there a way to send Outlook email from RShinyServer on ubuntu from a RShiny app?

Answer (score 7):

```
library(mailR)
sender <- "abc@gmail.com"

recipients <- c("bcd@gmail.com","xyz@gmail.com")

send.mail(
    from = sender, 
     to = recipients, 
     subject="Cash_Collected_Bank_transfer",
     Sys.Date(),
     "{}", body = Summary1, encoding = "utf-8", smtp = 
         list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, 
         user.name="abc@gmail.com", passwd="abc@1234", ssl=TRUE), 
     authenticate = TRUE, send = TRUE ,
     attach.files = c(path2), html = TRUE , inline = TRUE )
```

Comment: Although your answer may be correct, it is preferable to add explanatory text to help readers understand your code.

Comment: is there a way to encrypt the password?

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K: Saw this 4 yrs later, but here is my approach is to set environment variable  for the password in R (for anyone who will stumble upon this)

First write your password on your environment variable
`Sys.setenv(GMAIL_PWD = 'mypassword')`

Then call your env variable in your script

`passwd = Sys.getenv("GMAIL_PWD")`

This way you do not need to hardcode your password on the script. You could do the same thing with other variables

Comment: Note, you may need to use `<` and `>` in the "from" field to send from another mailbox address (see other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23413965/1255931).

Answer (score 5):

There is a new package called [emayili](https://datawookie.github.io/emayili/) with two very interesting promises:

- works on all manner of SMTP servers
- has minimal dependencies (or dependencies which are easily satisfied)

It seems early stages but promising nonetheless. Sending email is as simple as:

```
devtools::install_github("datawookie/emayili")
library(emayili)
library(dplyr)

email <- envelope() %>%
  from("alice@yahoo.com") %>%
  to("bob@google.com") %>%
  subject("This is a plain text message!") %>%
  body("Hello!")

smtp <- server(host = "smtp.gmail.com",
               port = 465,
               username = "bob@gmail.com",
               password = "bd40ef6d4a9413de9c1318a65cbae5d7")

smtp(email, verbose = TRUE)
```

Comment: can I use the same SMTP server if I am sending a message from a Yahoo account. Also, is this the email/pwd of sender or receiver?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to send an email via Gmail, anonymized or authenticated. Here is the code for anonymized:

```
library(mailR)
send.mail(from = "sender@gmail.com",
      to = c("Recipient 1 <recipient1@gmail.com>", "recipient2@gmail.com"),
      cc = c("CC Recipient <cc.recipient@gmail.com>"),
      bcc = c("BCC Recipient <bcc.recipient@gmail.com>"),
      subject = "Subject of the email",
      body = "Body of the email",
      smtp = list(host.name = "aspmx.l.google.com", port = 25),
      authenticate = FALSE,
      send = TRUE)
```

Make sure the recipient emails are Gmail too. It most likely goes to the spam folder in the Gmail account so make sure to mark it "**not spammed**".

You can find more info [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mailR/versions/0.4.1).

Answer (score 1):

I found the simplest way in Ubuntu is to run the one liner Terminal command in R.
No need for password.

> try(system("mutt -s 'Run is complete.' youremail@anymail.com < /dev/null", intern = TRUE))

You will need to install mutt in terminal before this.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `blastula` package from RStudio (Posit) for this. https://github.com/rstudio/blastula

I have tested this with my gmail account and it works well. The benefit of this package is that we can insert Markdown text, block-based components, and even HTML fragments. The resulting email message is responsive so it’ll look great on both large displays and mobile devices.

```
library(blastula)

date_time <- add_readable_time()

email <-
  compose_email(
    body = md(glue::glue(
      "Hello, 
      This is to let you know that I could successfully send an email from R. 
")),
    footer = md(glue::glue("Email sent on {date_time}."))
  )
```

You can run `email` in the console to see how the mail would look.

[image]

Send the email -

```
email |>
  smtp_send(
    to = "toemail@ygmail.com",
    from = "fromemail@gmail.com",
    subject = "Test Email",
    credentials = creds_file("gmail_creds")
  )
```

Before running the above line with `smtp_send` please go through the initial one time setup steps below which is important to send an email.

---

**What is `gmail_creds` ?**

`gmail_creds` is a file where your google account information is saved.

**How to create `gmail_creds` file?**

Now if you are using `blastula` package for the first time you need to give it permission to your email. For that create an app password from https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords . Note that, you will be allowed to create an app password only if you have turned on 2-factor authentication. Copy the app password generated from google.

Come back to R and run

```
create_smtp_creds_key(id = "gmail_creds",
                      provider = "gmail",
                      user = "fromemail@gmail.com")
```

A prompt would appear asking you to enter the password for `fromemail@gmail.com`. This is where you enter the app password that you had copied in the previous step.

Now you are good to send emails from R. You can run `smtp_send` function to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer an in-house solution with your server, you can call the linux sendmail.

```
EMAIL <- myEmail@gmail.com
cmd <- 'subject="Info server";body="This is an email"'
cmd <- paste("echo -e \"Subject:${subject}\n${body}\" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t \"", EMAIL, "\"")
system(cmd)
```