# Reading Email Attachment .xls in R

Tags: r, email, outlook

I am using R to read attached files from Outlook. I've tried already these steps and they work perfectly [Reading Email Attachment to R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857087/reading-email-attachment-to-r?noredirect=1&lq=1).

The problem is that my files are in a xls format so read.csv doesnt work.

I have this error:

```
data <- read.csv(attachment_file)
```

> Warning message:
>       In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
>        incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 
>       'C:\Users\GABRIE~1.BEN\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWmxRwP\file155c162721e8'

When I tried to open it with `read.excel` function I get this error

> data <- read_excel(attachment_file, sheet = 1)
>   Error: Missing file extension.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this "/" instead of this "\" in your file url.

Like this:
'C:/Users/GABRIE~1.BEN/......"

Comment: Thank you Giovana, the problem is not the "\" because if it were a csv file it works perfect, the problem is the format of the temp file = file155c162721e8 that is xls format