# How to use RDCOMClient to send Outlook email from a secondary account - translate existing VBA code?

Tags: r, outlook, rdcomclient

I am trying to send an email from a secondary email address using `RDCOMClient`. I took the advice from [How to retrieve Outlook inbox emails using R RDCOMClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573699/how-to-retrieve-outlook-inbox-emails-using-r-rdcomclient/42590894) and tried writing it in VBA and translating, but could not get the right commands.

Note: I can't use `SentOnBehalfOfName` because I don't have the necessary permission.

The below VBA and Python code both successfully send email from the secondary inbox.

**VBA**

```vb
Sub SendUsingAccount()

 Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account
 Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
 Set oAccount = Application.Session.Accounts.Item(2) 'Index of Mailbox
 Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 oMail.Subject = "Sent using MAPI Account"
 oMail.Recipients.Add "email@email.com"
 oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll
 oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount
 oMail.Send
End Sub
```

**Python**

```py
import win32com.client
o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
oacctouse = None
for oacc in o.Session.Accounts:
  if oacc.SmtpAddress == "myemail@email.com":
    oacctouse = oacc
    break

#print oacc   
#dir(oacc)
#oacc.CLSID
#oacc.GetAddressEntryFromID
Msg = o.CreateItem(0)
if oacctouse:
   Msg._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, oacctouse))  # Msg.SendUsingAccount = oacctouse
Msg.To="email@email.com"    
Msg.HTMLBody = "test env instance #"
Msg.Send()
```

**R**

Things I have tried in R in addition to guessing all combinations I can think of for `[["SMTP"]]`, `$SmtpAddress`, etc:

```
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outMail <- OutApp$CreateItem(0)
#1 :No Error, but email sends from primary inbox
oa<-OutApp[["Session"]][["Accounts"]]
second_inbox<-oa$Item(2) 
outMail[["SendUsingAccount"]]=second_inbox
#2: Runs, but sends from primary inbox
outMail[["SendUsingAccount"]]="myemail@email.com"
#From what I read emails need to be accessed with a number,not the name
#3 Runs, but sends from primary inbox (the Python index changes every run)
outMail[["SendUsingAccount"]]="oacc_id_from_Python"

#Rest of reproducible code
outMail[["To"]] = "email@email.com"
outMail[["subject"]] = "Alt Acc"
outMail[["body"]] = "test"
outMail$Send()
```

Related questions:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7afc9e42-ca4f-491b-8c50-19556fb4e1cf/sendusingaccount-does-not-work-in-outlook-2010-possible-bug?forum=outlookdev
- [Sending email in R via outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811679/sending-email-in-r-via-outlook),

Ideas?

Comment: Just posted a similar question there: I am trying to retrieve emails from a defined mailbox when several exist...https://stackoverflow.com/q/52649215/5224236

Comment: Where do you assign `outMail` in R?

Comment: Try placing the `SendUsingAccount` assignment just before `Send` as done in VBA.

Comment: did you ever answer this?

Comment: What kind of accountant is it? Exchange? POP3/SMTP?

Comment: Parfait - I tried changing the order, but got the same result (sends from primary inbox). Nova - No, I never answered this. I worked around it by using Python code for this section of my pipeline. Then I triggered the R and py scripts from a bat. @DmitryStreblechenko - it's an Exchange account.

Comment: @RustlessBroom, Tried to send the outlook email but the code fails in create item step itself. what is the issue??
code:```import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail```

Answer (score 1):

Source:
http://www.seancarney.ca/2020/10/07/sending-email-from-outlook-in-r/

```
# Send the message from an alternate account
Email[["sentonbehalfofname"]] = "alternate-sender@test.com"
```

This guy nailed it. :)

Comment: As I note in the question, I couldn't use 'sentonbehalfofname' because I didn't have the necessary permissions. Even without those permissions, I'm able to send emails from that account in VBA & python. The question was, how do you make that work in R?