# Outlook attachment saving script not working from Windows Command Prompt (works perfectly from RStudio)

Tags: r, outlook, save, email-attachments, rdcomclient

**Script Objective**
Save attachment files (.xlsx) from two emails to a network share.

**Issue**
R Script below works perfectly well in RStudio but fails when run from Windows command prompt.

**Error Message**

> < checkErrorInfo> 80020009 
>   No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo
>   checkErrorInfo -2147352567
>   Error: Exception occurred.
>   Execution halted

**R Code**

```
cat("\n##########################################################################################",
    "\n", format(Sys.time(), "%a %m/%d/%Y %X"), ": Starting Daily Attachment Save Script...",
    "\n##########################################################################################")

cat("\n", format(Sys.time(), "%a %m/%d/%Y %X"), ": Setting variables/constants/functions... ")

  library("RDCOMClient")
  library("lubridate")

  TodaysDate  <- Sys.Date()
  StartTime   <- Sys.time()
  currentUser <- Sys.getenv("USERNAME")
  tmpDir      <- Sys.getenv("TEMP")
  report_run_date_main <- Sys.Date()

  SendMail <- function(outFile,
                       ToEmail,
                       EmailSubject,
                       EmailBody,
                       AttachFile = TRUE,
                       CC = "me@me.com;"){

    OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
    outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)

    outMail[["sentonbehalfofname"]] = "me@me.com"
    outMail[["To"]] = ToEmail
    outMail[["CC"]] = CC
    outMail[["subject"]] = EmailSubject
    outMail[["HTMLBody"]] = paste0("<p>**** SYSTEM GENERATED EMAIL ****</p><br><p>", EmailBody, "</p>", sep = "")
    if (AttachFile == TRUE) {
      outMail[["Attachments"]]$Add(outFile)
    }
    outMail$Send()
    outMail <- NULL
    OutApp <- NULL
  }

  outlook_app <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
  search <- outlook_app$AdvancedSearch(
    "Inbox", paste0("(urn:schemas:httpmail:subject like 'EMAIL SUBJECT TO SEARCH%')")
  )
  results <- search$Results()

  save_folder <- paste0(Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE"), "\\Documents")

  get_attachment_names <- function(email) {
    number_attachments = email$Attachments()$Count()
    if (number_attachments == 0) {
      return("")
    }
    attachments <- purrr::map(
      seq(number_attachments), 
      function(x) email$Attachments(x)$FileName()
    )
    return(paste(attachments, sep = ", "))
  }

  msg1 <- ""
  msg2 <- ""

cat("done.")

cat("\n", format(Sys.time(), "%a %m/%d/%Y %X"), ": Saving attachemnts from daily emails... ") 
  for (i in 1:results$Count()) {
    # Error on next line, when run using command line
    gmt_date <- results$Item(i)$ReceivedTime()
    date_received <- as.POSIXct(gmt_date * (24 * 60 * 60), origin="1899-12-30", tz="GMT")

    date_received_dt <- format(date_received, "%Y-%m-%d")
    date_received_tm <- format(date_received, "%H:%M:%S %P")
    date_received_hr <- format(date_received, "%H")

    if(date_received >= Sys.Date()-1) {
      if(date_received_dt==Sys.Date()-1){
        if(date_received_hr>=16){
          email <- results$Item(i)
          attachment_file <- get_attachment_names(email)
          email$Attachments(1)$SaveAsFile(paste0(save_folder, attachment_file))
          msg1 <- paste(format(Sys.time(), "%a %m/%d/%Y %X"), 
                        "<br><br><b>Attachment name:</b>", attachment_file ,
                        "<br><b>Email received on:</b>", date_received, 
                        "<br><b>Subject:</b>", email$Subject(),
                        "<br><b>Save folder:</b>", save_folder)
        }
      } else{
        email <- results$Item(i)
        attachment_file <- get_attachment_names(email)
        email$Attachments(1)$SaveAsFile(paste0(save_folder, attachment_file))
        msg2 <- paste(format(Sys.time(), "%a %m/%d/%Y %X"), 
                      "<br><br><b>Attachment name:</b>", attachment_file ,
                      "<br><b>Email received on:</b>", date_received, 
                      "<br><b>Subject:</b>", email$Subject(),
                      "<br><b>Save folder:</b>", save_folder)
      }
    }
  }
cat("done.")


cat("\n", format(Sys.time(), "%a %m/%d/%Y %X"), ": Notifying users of attachment save status... ")
  if((nchar(msg1)==0)){
    SendMail(outFile = "",
             ToEmail = "me@me.com",
             EmailSubject = paste("[Action Required] Daily Attachment Save Error", Sys.Date()),
             EmailBody = paste("Helpful text 1 for troubleshooting"),
             AttachFile = F, CC = "")
  } else {
    SendMail(outFile = "",
             ToEmail = "users@many.com",
             EmailSubject = paste("Daily attachment saved", Sys.Date()),
             EmailBody = paste(msg1),
             AttachFile = F, CC = "")
  }

  if(nchar(msg2)==0){
    SendMail(outFile = "",
             SendMail(outFile = "",
             ToEmail = "me@me.com",
             EmailSubject = paste("[Action Required] Daily Attachment Save Error", Sys.Date()),
             EmailBody = paste("Helpful text 2 for troubleshooting"),
             AttachFile = F, CC = "")
  } else {
    SendMail(outFile = "",
             ToEmail = "users@many.com",
             EmailSubject = paste("Daily attachment saved", Sys.Date()),
             EmailBody = paste(msg2),
             AttachFile = F, CC = "")
  }
cat("done.")

cat("\n", format(Sys.time(), "%a %m/%d/%Y %X"), ": Garbage Collection... ")
  rm(list=ls())
cat("done.")

cat("\n########################################################################################",
    "\n", format(Sys.time(), "%a %m/%d/%Y %X"), ": Daily Attachment Save Script complete.",
    "\n########################################################################################")
```

**R Script Execution Command**

> C:\Progra~1\R\R-3.4.4\bin\i386\Rscript.exe --no-save --no-restore --verbose C:\Attachments_Save_Script.R > "C:\LOGS\L%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%*%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.log" 2> "C:\LOGS\E%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%*%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.log"

**Version Info**
Windows 10 Pro 64 bit (i7 vPro with 16 GB RAM)
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
Microsoft Outlook 2013 (15.0.5172.1000) MSO (15.0.5172.1000) 32-bit
RStudio 1.0.143

**Ask**
Has anyone come across this issue with RDCOMClient library at the command line? Is there a fix? Thank you.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: gmt_date <- results$Item(i)$ReceivedTime()

Answer (score 0):

Your code never checks if you actually have a `MailItem` object - you can also have `ReportItem` and `MeetingItem` objects, which do not expose the `ReceivedTime` property. Check if the `Class` property (exposed by all OOM objects) == `43` (`OlObjectClass.olMail`)

Comment: I see your point, thank you. I was under the impression that results <- search$Results() would only return MailItems. Additionally, I thought I would never have ReportItems or MeetingItems containing the search string I was using. Not sure if there is a way to explicitly force results <- search$Results() to return MailItems. Will try the solution shown here and provide an update https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573699/how-to-retrieve-outlook-inbox-emails-using-r-rdcomclient/42590894#42590894