# How to retrieve the body of an Outlook email in my inbox using R?

Tags: r, rdcomclient

I regularly use the R package RDCOMClient to send emails straight from R, but is there a way to use it to import the body of emails in my inbox into R?

Ive seen some answers on here like from here...
[How to retrieve Outlook inbox emails using R RDCOMClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573699/how-to-retrieve-outlook-inbox-emails-using-r-rdcomclient/42590894#42590894)

But none of these seem to work and they are rather old answers or there are errors when I run them.

I also can't find any tutorials or documentation on how to really use RDCOMClient in relation to Outlook emails. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach that can be considered :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

## create outlook object
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outlookNameSpace <- OutApp$GetNameSpace("MAPI")
fld <- outlookNameSpace$GetDefaultFolder(6)

# Check that we got the right folder
Cnt <- fld$Items()$Count()
emails <- fld$items
list_Text_Body <- list()

for(i in 1 : Cnt)
{
  print(i)
  list_Text_Body[[i]] <- emails(i)[["Body"]]
}
```

Comment: When i run it all, the for loop doesnt out put anything

Comment: Do you have emails in your outlook? On my end, the code works very well. You can print the content of list_Text_Body with print(list_Text_Body)

Comment: I think i understand how this works now. Yes i do have emails in my inbox, if i were to want to pull the most recent email, how would i call that? print(list_Text_Body[[??]]) Secondary question, is it possible to grab emails from a secondary inbox

Comment: I am not sure of what you mean by a secondary inbox. Can you give more details?

Answer (score 0):

To sort the emails by time, you can use the field ReceivedTime as follows :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

## create outlook object
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outlookNameSpace <- OutApp$GetNameSpace("MAPI")
fld <- outlookNameSpace$GetDefaultFolder(6)

# Check that we got the right folder
Cnt <- fld$Items()$Count()
emails <- fld$items
list_Text_Body <- list()
list_Received_Time <- list()

for(i in 1 : Cnt)
{
  print(i)
  list_Text_Body[[i]] <- emails(i)[["Body"]]
  list_Received_Time[[i]] <- tryCatch(emails(i)[["ReceivedTime"]], error = function(e) NA)
}

vector_Text_Body <- unlist(list_Text_Body)
vector_Received_Time <- unlist(list_Received_Time)
vector_Text_Body_Ordered <- vector_Text_Body[order(vector_Received_Time)]
```