# Extracting Zip+CSV file from attachment w/ Image in Body of Email

Tags: r, email-attachments, unzip, sendmailr, rdcomclient

I receive daily emails where there is an attachment containing 1 zip file containing 1 csv file.

In the body of my email, there is an image that is being recognized as another attachment I am pretty sure.

[image]

The below script works when there is only text in the body of the email but with the "Adobe Marketing Cloud" image, it is screwing up the script.

Is there a way I can only read maybe the first attachment read (assuming that will be the zip file)?

Here is my script:

```
library(readr)
library(RDCOMClient)
outlook_app <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
search <- outlook_app$AdvancedSearch(
  "Inbox",
  "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject = 'SUBJECTNAME'"
)

Sys.sleep(5) # Wait a hot sec!


results <- search$Results() # Saves search results into results object

Sys.sleep(5) # Wait a hot sec!

results$Item(1)$ReceivedTime() # Received time of first search result

as.Date("1899-12-30") + floor(results$Item(1)$ReceivedTime()) # Received 
date

# Iterates through results object to pull out all of the items
for (i in 1:results$Count()) {
  if (as.Date("1899-12-30") + floor(results$Item(i)$ReceivedTime()) 
      == as.Date(Sys.Date())) {
    email <- results$Item(i)
  }
}

attachment_file <- tempfile()
email$Attachments(1)$SaveAsFile(attachment_file)

##Automatically Determine csv file name
file_name<-unzip(attachment_file,list=TRUE)
csv_file<-file_name$Name

##Read CSV File
newly_read_data <- read_csv(unz(attachment_file,csv_file))
```

The error comes here:

```
file_name<-unzip(attachment_file,list=TRUE)
Error in unzip(attachment_file, list = TRUE) : 
  zip file 'C:\Temp\Rtmp86Gnzp\file29904a23387b' cannot be opened
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: @mdneuzerling any experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`email$Attachments(1)$SaveAsFile(attachment_file)` will save the *first* attachment to the file path defined by `attachment_file`, according to some unknown ordering. If you're sure there'll only be one file with a ".zip" extension then you can use the `FileName` method to check that the name of the attachment contains ".zip":

```
attachment_file <- tempfile()

for (i in 1:email$Attachments()$Count()) {
    attachment <- email$Attachments(i)
    if (grepl(".zip", attachment$FileName(), ignore.case = TRUE)) {
        attachment$SaveAsFile(attachment_file)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @mdneuzerling, thanks for you help! There is an error coming up saying: `Error in email.Attachments.Count() : 
  could not find function "email.Attachments.Count"` I tried the other way you mentioned also above and it through a syntax error.

Comment: Also, after I run above, should I still run #Automatically Determine csv file name section?

Comment: Darn. I'll look up the correct code tomorrow and amend my answer. Sorry about that! The property [certainly exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/attachments-count-property-outlook), but the line between property and method is very blurry here.

I'm afraid I don't know anything about the package you're using to unzip files, but yes, you would then go through to unzip the attachment and load the .csv in it.

Comment: Ok sounds good, thanks for looking into this @mdneuzerling. I'll do some research also in the meantime on the link you provided.

Comment: @NickKnauer Try that now. There were a few errors, but the big one was using grep instead of grepl.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks for the help @mdneuzerling. Appreciate you spending time looking into this.