# SMTP connection with RCurl/Curl Package

Tags: r, curl, smtp, libcurl, rcurl

Currently, I use the following line to send emails with R.

```
system("curl --ssl-reqd smtp://smtp.test.com:587 --mail-from jan@test.com --mail-rcpt jan@test.com --upload-file email.txt --insecure -u user:password")
```

I would like to use the **RCurl** or **Curl** package to send this request *natively* from R. Is it possible to send requests using the smtp protocol with RCurl or Curl? I don't like to use the **mailR** package due to its **RJava** dependency. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Natively is maybe not the right word. From Outlook client, see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811679/sending-email-in-r-via-outlook ; there's a GMAIL client too : http://cran.univ-paris1.fr/web/packages/gmailr/index.html

Comment: Hi @EugèneAdell! Thanks for your fast reply. Unfortunately, I am looking for a solution that's independent of any provider and does not require any dependencies such as Outlook.

Comment: Why do you consider your curl command being not native enough ?

Comment: Because I would like to execute the command directly from R without creating the *email.txt* every time. Additionally, I would like to use the function on Windows and Linux without installing non-R dependencies every time.

Comment: You understand that you need anything which looks like a mail client, and usually, don't re-invent the wheel. Maybe should you consider that file.txt can be kept and archived for later debugging for example. It is not what you want, but relying on curl makes sense.