# Sending email attachment in R via Outlook

Tags: r, outlook, rdcomclient

I need to send an email attachment in R via Microsoft Outlook.  All of the code on this page works except for the line of code that sends an email attachment.  [Sending email in R via outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811679/sending-email-in-r-via-outlook)

The line of code that does NOT work for me is:

```
outMail[["Attachments"]]$Add(path_to_attach_file)
```

Does anyone have any advice or suggestions?  Thank you in advance for your help!

I'm sorry; I just realized that it's difficult to read my error messages and block of code, in my replies to your comments.

The following is the error message I got:

```
checkErrorInfo> 80020009 
No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo
checkErrorInfo -2147352567
Error: Exception occurred.
```

This is the entire block of code I ran:

```
require(RDCOMClient)
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outMail <- OutApp$CreateItem(0)
outMail[["bcc"]] <- "someone@someemail.com"
outMail[["subject"]] <- "TEST"
outMail[["body"]] <- "This is a TEST"
outMail[["Attachments"]]$Add("A:/Automate_Emails/Test_Attachment.pdf")
outMail$Send()
```

Please note that I only got the error message when I ran the 2nd to last line of code, which is:

```
outMail[["Attachments"]]$Add("A:/Automate_Emails/Test_Attachment.pdf")
```

Thank you so much for your help!  Best Regards.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: can you put the actual code you have tried here?

Comment: Specifically, include entire code block with all `library` lines.

Comment: Sorry, for not including my error message and entire code block with library line.  My error message is:  checkErrorInfo> 80020009 
No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo
checkErrorInfo -2147352567
Error: Exception occurred.

Comment: The entire block of code that I tried is:  require(RDCOMClient)
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outMail <- OutApp$CreateItem(0)
outMail[["bcc"]] <- "someone@someemail.com"
outMail[["subject"]] <- "TEST"
outMail[["body"]] <- "This is a TEST"
outMail[["Attachments"]]$Add("Z:/AutomateEmails/Test_Attachment.pdf")
outMail$Send()                 All of the code worked except for:  outMail[["Attachments"]]$Add("Z:/AutomateEmails/Test_Attachment.pdf")                     Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue lies in the fact that you have not escape the escape when adding the attachment

You have the below

```
 outMail[["Attachments"]]$Add("A:/Automate_Emails/Test_Attachment.pdf")
```

You it should look like this

```
 outMail[["Attachments"]]$Add("A:\\Automate_Emails\\Test_Attachment.pdf")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, mannym!  Your solution works.  I really appreciate your help.  Take care.