# R: Is there a way to automatically count the number of emails in an outlook folder?

Tags: r, outlook, directory

Is it possible to write an r code that would auto update how many emails were in my outlook subfolder XYZ? I need to use that number (it'll count the number of bounced emails) as a variable in my code.

I've never integrated R and outlook and am not really sure where to start. Any pointers/ sample code would be appreciated!!

Comment: You can use R to call a VBA script, which can directly reference MSOffice objects: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37086738/4421870). I think you can just look up a VBA solution for counting emails, then call that within R.

Comment: Using  package `RDCOMClient` I think you could manage something : http://www.omegahat.net/RDCOMClient/ . In this link they mention only excel but I used it to interact with powerpoint so outlook shouldn't be so different.

Comment: @Ellie did you manage to get what you wanted ?

Answer (score 4):

The library `RDCOMClient` will be useful for you, here's what I could do on my side:

```
library(RDCOMClient)
ol <- COMCreate("outlook.Application")
objFolder <- ol$ActiveExplorer()$CurrentFolder()
objFolder$Items()$Count()
# [1] 489
```

The way it works is not straightforward and the doc of the package is not super easy, but here's how I find my way around it :

Use the `VBA` reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.itemproperties

It gives you the object structure, it's sometimes easier to google than to navigate it directly.

Find out how people do it in regular `VBA`, and translate it in `RDCOMClient` syntax.

For example for this case I found on [this link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1513-outlook-count-emails-per-day.html) the following vba lines of code :

```
Set objFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count
```

And translated them as shown above.

With a bit of trial and error, looking for existing code and tweaking with the vba reference you will hopefully find your way!