# Sending email in R via Outlook 2016

Tags: r, email, windows-10, outlook-2016, rdcomclient

I've been using RDCOMClient package as described here [Sending email in R via outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811679/sending-email-in-r-via-outlook). Everything was working fine with Outlook 2010 and Windows 7. The script is not working since I've changed the system to Windows 10 with Outlook 2016.

Here is the script:

```
library(RDCOMClient)

OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
outMail[["To"]] = "test@test.com"
outMail[["subject"]] = "test"
outMail[["body"]] = "Test."
outMail$Send()
```

It fails at the last line with the error as follows:

80004004 
No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo
checkErrorInfo -2147467260
Error: Operation aborted

Suggested workaround is to open message box and simulate pressing Ctrl+Enter:

```
library(KeyboardSimulator)
library(RDCOMClient)

OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
outMail[["To"]] = "test@test.com"
outMail[["subject"]] = "test"
outMail[["body"]] = "Test."
outMail$Display()
Sys.sleep(3)

keybd.press('Ctrl+Enter')
```

But this method is not 100% reliable.

Do you have any idea how to make outMail$Send() work again?

Thank you!

Comment: I am using the exact construct above on Windows 10, Outlook 2016 (v1803), and the `outMail$Send()` works for me.