# Sending emails through rmarkdown

Tags: r, html-email, r-markdown

Is there a way in rmarkdown, where after you create your html document, you can add a button to email a report that is created in the rmarkdown doc after manipulating with tables? Or is this feature only available in Shiny?

And on top of this, is there a way to import new data into an rmarkdown document without using RStudio. So for example, if I created a reproducible rmarkdown document, can I add a button that can add data from a csv or once again is this only available in Shiny?

I am basically trying to figure out a free way to have clients/coworkers take my documents and let them takeover without them knowing how to use R in the future. Shiny doesn't allow me to do this because the free version requires others to have R installed already and copy and paste the code whereas Shiny Pro costs a good bit of money.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306362/run-r-script-from-command-line how to run R-Programms from the command-line and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412265/how-do-you-send-email-from-r on how to send emails via R. Combine them and you get what you want - without RShiny

Comment: haha @rawr in due time...

Comment: @Floo0 thanks I'll check that out

Comment: For clarification, are you asking if you can have the coworker press a button on their end and receive and 'updated' set of tables/figures? If so, this is going to require a server running R somewhere, whether it's Shiny or something else.

Comment: A button in the HTML doc to mail itself? With an inline JavaScript `mailto`, probably. For more complicated stuff, [`mailR`](https://github.com/rpremraj/mailR) might be useful, but for anything to get processed you need an R environment. Importing data definitely requires an R environment. Maybe shinyapps.io or your own install of Shiny Server?