# How do i send mail over IMAP in R

Tags: r, email, exchange-server

I looked up sending mail in R and found that the libarary SendMailR can be used for smpt but does not seem to have any IMAP related options.

An example of what I've found so far. 
[how do you send email from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412265/how-do-you-send-email-from-r)

Answer (score 6):

You are confused. Mail flows in two ways:

1. To you -- that is IMAP, POP, ... and you do not *send* that way but receive.
2. From you -- that is SMTP and you (generally) need to interact with a mail-sending program like sendmail, exim, qmail, ... or the smtp service offered by the Google GMail back end. As I recall, SendMailR can deal with these.

So in short, _there is no sending via IMAP. (Check eg the advanced email setup options of your smartphone. They generally split it between receiving -- my point 1. above -- and sending as in point 2.)

The simplest way to send then depends on your operating system.  These details matter.