# Automation of running a R script

Tags: sql, r

I run an R script which contains SQL query and import the .csv file and mail it to the manager and operations daily. But I am looking forward to automating this process so kindly help me with the steps I should do to automate.

The .csv file has the day stamp.

```
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='*******', password='******', dbname='********', host='*****8***')

setwd('C:\\Users\\******\\Work\\2. ****\\26. Cluster_Bags')

#Change the data here 
startdate='2017-07-24'

sql_text=paste("SELECT ********************************,


FROM ********************
WHERE ***********
                ")
ClusterwiseBag=dbGetQuery(mydb,sql_text)

#Creates a file with the name "Clusterbag date.csv"           
b=paste("Clusterbag",startdate,".csv",sep="")

write.csv(ClusterwiseBag,b)
```

Comment: Are you using `PHP`? If yes then use `cron job` for this.

Comment: You may 1) create a batch file that runs your script (it would be a .bat file that consists of something like `"c:\Program Files (x86)\R\R-3.3.0\bin\x64\R" CMD BATCH d:/Data/Test/YourScript.r` 2) Schedule that batch file to run once a day with Windows Task Scheduler (if using Windows; other OS have their own schedulers). Also, to send an e-mail from R, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412265/how-do-you-send-email-from-r

Answer (score 1):

This is how I go about automating scripts:

First change startdate to:
        startdate = Sys.Date()

If you like, add automatic email, for example with:
    library(mailR)
    send.mail(from = "from@gmail.com",
          to = c("to1@gmail.com", "to2@gmail.com"),
          subject = "Update", body = " ", authenticate = T,
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465,
                      user.name = "from", passwd = "123456", ssl = T),
          attach.files = c(b))

Then use the RStudio Add-in [taskscheduleR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/taskscheduleR/vignettes/taskscheduleR.html) to let the script run on a daily basis.

Comment: Error in send.mail(from = "", to = c("***"),  : 
  could not find function "send.mail"

Comment: Maybe the library is not installed yet? Try     install.packages("mailR")     first before      library(mailR)    and    send.mail(...)