# is it possible to send a notification to a specific person if a variable changes in SQL

Tags: r, sql-server

I have models in SQL that update the data everyday automatically. Info about the models is stored in a table. One of the columns I called "error". It is a column with zeros, which change to 1 if the performance of the model  is below a certain threshold. Now my question is whether it is possible that I get notified if an entry of the "error" column becomes 1.

The models I discussed are R scripts that I run in SQL. The scripts predict whether a customer makes a purchase or not.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: What RDBMS? What is a "Model"?

Comment: Hint - Search for Triggers.

Comment: If you have a script that's updating this variable based on certain conditions... why not just use that same R script to send an email notification?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412265/how-do-you-send-email-from-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the R script to send an email.

this will explain how to do it:
[how do you send email from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412265/how-do-you-send-email-from-r)

Answer (score 1):

To get a more immediate notification than an email, you can also use a tool like [Notify17](https://notify17.net), which would send you a push notification on your browser/mobile phone (it is very easy to miss out emails).

There is a basic [`R` recipe](https://notify17.net/recipes/r/) for it, which boils down to:

```r
notify17 <- function(rawAPIKey, title, content = '') {
  hookURL = paste0("https://hook.notify17.net/api/raw/", rawAPIKey)
  query <- list(title   = title,
                content = content)
  resp <- httr::POST(hookURL, body = query, encode = "form")
  print(httr::content(resp))
}

# Usage:

notify17('RAW_API_KEY',
         "Model training finished")
```

All you need is to get a raw API key from the [dashboard](https://dash.notify17.net/#/rawAPIKeys) and use it in a script.