# R send email with attachment using sendmailR

Tags: r, sendmailr

I'm trying to attach a file in R using sendmailR.

Is this possible?

excluding attach.files line sends email without issue.

```
to <- "<me@localhost>"
subject <- "test attachment"
body <- list("test")
attach.files = c("test.jpeg"),
sendmail(from, to, subject, body,
control=list(smtpServer="192.168.0.51"))} 
Error: unexpected '}' in:
"sendmail(from, to, subject, body,
control=list(smtpServer="192.168.0.51"))}"
```

Comment: Have you tried Googling it? Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885660/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-from-r-in-windows) help?

Comment: It also looks like you just have a syntax error there. Where does this `}` belongs to?

Comment: When I save the file I get an error and i've searched google with so results; > saveChart('jpeg')
Error in assign(".chob", x, env) : 
  cannot change value of locked binding for '.chob'
> dev.off()
null device 
          1

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
to <- "<me@localhost>"
subject <- "test attachment"
attachment -> mime_part (x = "test.jpeg")
body <- list("test", attachment)
sendmail(from, to, subject, body,
control=list(smtpServer="192.168.0.51"))}
```

Comment: Could you provide an explanation?