# Sent mail in R with results, package {mail}

Tags: r, email, attachment

I've tried some packages in R to send mail, but the one that works was `library(mail)`

I like this package, function `sendmail`  is so easy to use with no problems

```
x=matrix(seq(1:9),nrow=3)
for (i in 1:100000){
x=log(sqrt(x)%*%t(x))
}
sendmail("mymail@mail.com", subject="Notification from R",message="Calculation finished!", password="rmail")
```

***NOTE***: you should keep this password and don't change it `"rmail"`

But I can't send some attachments the result of `x` (for a simple example)

I know that this question exists, but I couldn't find the answer till now. The existing answers are too complicated and sometime does not solve the problem.

Thank you for help.

Comment: The documentation of the `mail` package does not mention anything about attachments. I think you should probably use `sendmailR` instead, if you want to send an attachment (which needs to be a file and not an R vector). Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885660/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-from-r-in-windows)